# How multipart form data upload handles large file

Tags: java, resteasy, quarkus

I am using quarkus framework for java application.I have created 2 rest apis for consuming file data.

```
    @POST
    @Path("file")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response uploadFile(byte[] fileData) {
        System.out.println("Received file of size = " + fileData.length);
        String s = new String(fileData);
       return Response.ok().build();
    }

    @POST
    @Path("files")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void uploadFile(@MultipartForm FormData fileData) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Received file of size = ");
        System.out.println(fileData.file.length());
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
```

FormData class looks like this

```
public class FormData {

    @FormParam("file")
    @PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public File file;
}
```

While both of these rest endpoint works fine for small files. But if i upload file as big as 700MB first endpoint fails with OOM issue while file upload with multipart-form succeed. Can someone explain how memory is managed in case of multipart-form upload?

Comment: I'm not a REST API expat but this is certainly a know-how question. I think for such a generic problem you should use an existing solution, i.e an existing API, Library or some solution from known companies. As building multipart upload for a rest api is going to be like inventing the wheel again. Please check multi part upload rest api frameworks.

Comment: Can you explain why OOM error occur in first api?

Answer (score 1):

The second API saves the file to a temp file on the file system. (which I believe is being automatically deleted when the call completes and the File is closed)

The first API saves the file to a byte stream (array) in memory - that's why you're getting an OOM error.